# Removing a layer property in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am working on a digitizing application that also lets users delete a layer’s attribute (i.e. properties) by selecting a property from a dropdown.

The workflow: a user selects a feature (*someFeature*) by clicking it on the map and selects a property of that feature in a dropdown (*removeProperty*).
Now *removeProperty* should be removed from *someFeature*.

```
var features = layer.getSource().getFeatures();

features.forEach(function (feature) {

    if (feature === someFeature) {

        var properties = feature.getProperties();

        for (var prop in properties) {

            if (properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

                if (prop === removeProperty) {

                    delete feature.getProperties()[prop];

                }

            }
        }

    }

});
```

The problem is that the line `delete feature.getProperties()[prop];` does not work to achieve this as *getProperties()* seems to simply return a new object from which the key is then deleted (instead of being deleted from the actual layer).

Using *setProperties* by assigning an object without the selected key also does not work as *setProperties*, as stated in the docs *changes any existing properties and adds new ones (it does not remove any existing properties).*

So, how can I remove a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
delete feature.getProperties()[prop];
```

you just need to use the following

```
feature.unset(prop);
```

For the docs reference, go to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Object-BaseObject.html#unset